# Dictionary.get_Item() performance

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

I just had a look at the profiler and saw a big spike in the Dictionary.get_Item() method, in the String.memcpy() method. I am using a Dictionary with keys of type enum and values of type struct. Can someone tell me how this can happen?

Heres the Code Snippet:

```
private void TransformBone(JointType joint, int boneIndex)
    {
        boneTransform = bones[boneIndex];

        if (boneTransform == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        int iJoint = (int)joint;
        if (iJoint < 0 || !this.IsJointTracked(comp.Body.joints[joint]) || !ShallJointBeTracked(joint))
        {
            return;
        }
        jointRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        if (comp.Body.isTracked)
        {
            jointRotation = comp.Body.joints[joint].rotation;
        }

        if (jointRotation == Quaternion.identity)
            return;

        Kinect2AvatarRot(jointRotation, boneIndex);
        if (smoothFactor != 0f)
        {
            boneTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(boneTransform.rotation, newRotation, smoothFactor * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            boneTransform.rotation = newRotation;
        }
    }

    private Quaternion Kinect2AvatarRot(Quaternion jointRotation, int boneIndex)
    {
        newRotation = jointRotation * initialRotations[boneIndex];

        totalRotation = newRotation.eulerAngles + this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(totalRotation);

        return newRotation;
    }





 public struct KinectBody
    {
        public Dictionary<JointType, KinectJoint> joints;
        public bool isTracked;
        public ulong trackingID;
        public Vector3 position;
        public Vector3 hipsDirection;
        public Vector3 shouldersDirection;
        public float bodyTurnAngle;
        public Vector3 leftArmDirection;
        public Vector3 rightArmDirection;

        public KinectBody(Body body)
        {
            joints = new Dictionary<JointType, KinectJoint>(new JointTypeComparer());
            Dictionary<JointType, Windows.Kinect.Joint> rawJoints = body.Joints;

            foreach (JointType type in rawJoints.Keys)
            {
                joints[type] = new KinectJoint(rawJoints[type]);
            }
            position = joints[JointType.SpineMid].position;
            isTracked = body.IsTracked;
            trackingID = body.TrackingId;
            hipsDirection = Vector3.zero;
            shouldersDirection = Vector3.zero;
            bodyTurnAngle = 0;
            leftArmDirection = Vector3.zero;
            rightArmDirection = Vector3.zero;
        }

        public void ModifyJoint(JointType type, KinectJoint joint)
        {
            joints[type] = joint;
        }
    }



 public class JointTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<JointType>
    {
        bool IEqualityComparer<JointType>.Equals(JointType x, JointType y)
        {
            return x == y;
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<JointType>.GetHashCode(JointType obj)
        {
            return (int)obj;
        }
    }
```

The spike happens in the TransformBone method.

Comment: If your elements are structs, then a copy of them will be returned by get_Item(), which will take a copy of each string in the struct. This causes String.memcpy() to be called.

Comment: Dictionary.get_Item() is amortized O(1).  Very good perf.  But any fast code can be made slow by calling it often enough.  Or by using a struct when you should have used a class, a struct needs to be copied.  If your profiler doesn't show any of *your* code as a bottleneck then it usually tells you that you can stop profiling.

Comment: Okay thank you for the answer HansPassant but it takes up to 5 ms on a high performance machine.

Comment: So in a typical Kinect app that observes a human moving around and runs for, oh, 5 minutes while testing, your profiler shows you that it takes 0.017% of the execution time.  You are done.

Comment: No the spike appears about one time each minute. The average execution time for one frame is between 0.2 and 0.5 ms on the machine iam testing on. But this spike takes up to 5 ms.

Comment: @Hans Passant, what does amortized mean?

Comment: @Bgl86 It means that it averages to O(1), but implies that occasionally it might have to do some extra work (e.g. expanding arrays) that causes one particular call to be, say, O(N)

Comment: @LasseKlüver Have you considered that the garbage collector might be running occasionally?

Comment: There are so many dictionaries involved in your code. Of which one are you talking about? The first on (`bones[boneIndex]`) does not contain structs, because you check the value for null. `comp.Body.joints[joint]`is accessed more than once. By the way, using structs is more often the wrong decision than the right.

Comment: @Matthew Watson No i havent, but if the garbage collector would cause the spikes, wouldnt i see a GC.Collect spike in the profiler?